# Como padronizar a entrada de telefone em um TextBox C#

Tags: c#

Olá, estou fazendo um sistema de Cadastro de Clientes e estou com um problema que não faço ideia de como arrumar, sei que é "simples" mas estou a pouco programando e não achei nenhuma forma que realmente funcione.

Para cadastrar um cliente existe o campo de telefone onde fiz um tratamento para organizar o número, sem mascara.

```
protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLostFocus(e);
            this.BackColor = Color.White;

            string TelCel;
            TelCel = this.Text;
            string result = TelCel;
            {
                if (TelCel.Length == 13)
                {
                    this.Text = TelCel.Insert(0, "(").Insert(3, ")").Insert(9, "-");
                }
                if (TelCel.Length == 11)
                {
                    this.Text = TelCel.Insert(0, "(").Insert(3, ")").Insert(9, "-");
                }
                if (TelCel.Length == 10)
                {
                this.Text = TelCel.Insert(0, "(").Insert(3, ")").Insert(8, "-");
                }
                {
                    if ((TelCel.Length != 11) && (TelCel.Length != 10))
                    {
                        this.Text = TelCel;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Ao digitar o telefone na mão ele sairá assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem ao copiar e colar o telefone do WhatsApp ou outro lugar ele não faz a formatação: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem ele entra no Banco de dados das duas formas, mas caso eu queira fazer uma consulta não consigo devido os Parenteses, gostaria de saber como padronizar o numero de telefone, seja no Ctrl+c, Ctrl+v ou digitando a mão.

Agradeço desde já pela ajuda!

Comment: Isso é Windows Forms? O ideal aí é usar um componente com máscara.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde!
Eu usaria o maskedTextBox ao invés do textbox.

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Colocando as seguintes propriedades:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Digitando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Copiando e Colando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado Marcelo e Obrigado LINQ pela ajuda, também consegui criando uma classe de TextBox especifico para telefones, assim consigo usar em todo o meu projeto o mesmo controle em todo o projeto!
Adicionei apenas 3 linhas dentro da classe e consegui resolver o problema, até agora funcionou.. kk

Para quem interessar, segue o código, espero poder ajudar alguém.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Telefone.Controle
 {
class txtTelefone: TextBox
{
        protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnGotFocus(e);
        }

        protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLostFocus(e);
            this.BackColor = Color.White;

            //Linhas adicionadas para apagar qualquer espaço vazio do TextBox
            string str = this.Text;
            str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s", "");
            this.Text = str;

            string TelCel;
            TelCel= this.Text;
            string result = TelCel;
            {
                if (TelCel.Length == 12)
                {
                    this.Text = TelCel.Insert(0, "(").Insert(3, ")");
                }
                if (TelCel.Length == 13)
                {
                    this.Text = TelCel.Insert(0, "(").Insert(3, ")").Insert(9, "-");
                }
                if (TelCel.Length == 11)
                {
                    this.Text = TelCel.Insert(0, "(").Insert(3, ")").Insert(9, "-");
                }
                if (TelCel.Length == 10)
                {
                    this.Text = TelCel.Insert(0, "(").Insert(3, ")").Insert(8, "-");
                }
                {
                    if ((TelCel.Length != 11) && (TelCel.Length != 10) && (TelCel.Length != 12)) 
                    {
                        this.Text = TelCel;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnKeyDown(e);
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
            {
                this.Text = "";
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }
        }
        protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnKeyPress(e);
            if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)) return;
            if (char.IsControl(e.KeyChar)) return;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
}
}
```